# Mapping Group operation

Tags: group-theory

If G is a group, let us deﬁne an operation $\delta G$ on $|G|$ by $\delta G(x, y) = x\cdot y^{−1}$. Does the pair $G_0 = (|G|, \delta G)$ determine the group $(|G|, ·, −1, e)$? (I.e., if $G1$ and $G2$ yield the same pair, $G_0 1 = G_0 2$, must $G1 = G2$ ? Some students have asked whether by “=” I here mean “∼ =”. No, I mean “=”.)

Comment: What does $xy-1$ mean?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Randall, it's x.(y pow(-1)). Sorry didnt get it properly, will edit

Comment: If $\cdot$ is the operation in one group and $*$ is the operation in the other, then $x \cdot y = \delta G_1(x, y^{-1})= \delta G_2(x, y^{-1})= x * y$. Since the underlying set is also the same the groups must be equal

Comment: I am assuming that your "standard" version of a group satisfied the standard axioms. But what axioms are you assuming that $x/y$ satisfies? You need to specify, I reckon. I think that there's a paper by Graham Higman and Bernard Neumann in 1952 which gives a single axiom for $/$, and then shows how to get the usual operations, and shows it is a group. Here's the axiom: $ x / ((((x / x) / y) / z) / (((x / x) / x) / z)) = y$.

Comment: I'm a beginner to groups. Just that i found this question in a text book so there must be those assumed axioms of standard group.